# Lotus Notes plugin on Java

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I need some help concerning writing widget for Lotus Notes on Java. My problem is : I created a plugin according to this tutorial : [Developing a simple plug-in for Lotus Notes](http://www.domiclipse.com/domiclipse/web.nsf/d6plinks/FRUX-7LV42L)

But there is no information how to write any code. Also I failed to find anything using Google. To be more specific:

1. When I click some email in Notes Client I need to fetch this email address and show it on my widget.
2. When I click some link I need to open this link in a browser.

Could anyone help me and provide some example? Thanks a lot in advance! Here is my code:

```
package com.domiclipse.tutorial1.views;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.Action;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IMenuListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IMenuManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IToolBarManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.Separator;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DoubleClickEvent;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IDoubleClickListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITableLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerSorter;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.ui.IActionBars;
import org.eclipse.ui.ISharedImages;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchActionConstants;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;


/**
 * This sample class demonstrates how to plug-in a new
 * workbench view. The view shows data obtained from the
 * model. The sample creates a dummy model on the fly,
 * but a real implementation would connect to the model
 * available either in this or another plug-in (e.g. the workspace).
 * The view is connected to the model using a content provider.
 * <p>
 * The view uses a label provider to define how model
 * objects should be presented in the view. Each
 * view can present the same model objects using
 * different labels and icons, if needed. Alternatively,
 * a single label provider can be shared between views
 * in order to ensure that objects of the same type are
 * presented in the same way everywhere.
 * <p>
 */

public class SampleView extends ViewPart {
    private Action action1;
    private Action action2;
    private Action doubleClickAction;

    /*
     * The content provider class is responsible for
     * providing objects to the view. It can wrap
     * existing objects in adapters or simply return
     * objects as-is. These objects may be sensitive
     * to the current input of the view, or ignore
     * it and always show the same content 
     * (like Task List, for example).
     */

    class ViewContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
        public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }
        public void dispose() {
        }
        public Object[] getElements(Object parent) {
            return new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
        }
    }
    class ViewLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider {
        public String getColumnText(Object obj, int index) {
            return getText(obj);
        }
        public Image getColumnImage(Object obj, int index) {
            return getImage(obj);
        }
        public Image getImage(Object obj) {
            return PlatformUI.getWorkbench().
                    getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_ELEMENT);
        }
    }
    class NameSorter extends ViewerSorter {
    }

    /**
     * The constructor.
     */
    public SampleView() {
    }

    /**
     * This is a callback that will allow us
     * to create the viewer and initialize it.
     */
    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    viewer = new TableViewer(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    viewer.setContentProvider(new ViewContentProvider());
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new ViewLabelProvider());
    viewer.setSorter(new NameSorter());
    viewer.setInput(getViewSite());
        makeActions();
        hookContextMenu();
        hookDoubleClickAction();
        contributeToActionBars();
    }

    private void hookContextMenu() {
        MenuManager menuMgr = new MenuManager("#PopupMenu");
        menuMgr.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
        menuMgr.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
            public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager manager) {
                SampleView.this.fillContextMenu(manager);
            }
        });
//      Menu menu = menuMgr.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
        //viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);
        //getSite().registerContextMenu(menuMgr, viewer);
    }

    private void contributeToActionBars() {
        IActionBars bars = getViewSite().getActionBars();
        fillLocalPullDown(bars.getMenuManager());
        fillLocalToolBar(bars.getToolBarManager());
    }

    private void fillLocalPullDown(IMenuManager manager) {
        manager.add(action1);
        manager.add(new Separator());
        manager.add(action2);
    }

    private void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager manager) {
        manager.add(action1);
        manager.add(action2);
        // Other plug-ins can contribute there actions here
        manager.add(new Separator(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
    }

    private void fillLocalToolBar(IToolBarManager manager) {
        manager.add(action1);
        manager.add(action2);
    }

    private void makeActions() {
        action1 = new Action() {
            public void run() {
                showMessage("Action 1 executed");
            }
        };
        action1.setText("Action 1");
        action1.setToolTipText("Action 1 tooltip");
        action1.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
            getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));

        action2 = new Action() {
            public void run() {
                showMessage("Action rehrhrhertrSd");
            }
        };
        action2.setText("Action 2");
        action2.setToolTipText("Action 2 tooltip");
        action2.setImageDescriptor(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().
                getImageDescriptor(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_TSK));
        doubleClickAction = new Action() {
            public void run() {
                //ISelection selection = viewer.getSelection();
                //Object obj = ((IStructuredSelection)selection).getFirstElement();
                //showMessage("Double-click detected on "+obj.toString());
            }
        };
    }

    private void hookDoubleClickAction() {
        //viewer.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {
        //  public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
        //      doubleClickAction.run();
        //  }
        //});
    }
    private void showMessage(String message) {
        //MessageDialog.openInformation(
        //  viewer.getControl().getShell(),
        //  "Sample View",
        //  message);
    }

    /**
     * Passing the focus request to the viewer's control.
     */
    public void setFocus() {
    //  viewer.getControl().setFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Include what you've achieved so far.

Comment: Now tell us what happens when you run your code. Does it do anything at all?  When you click an email address, what happens? Re your item 2, clicking links to open in a browser is native functionality in Lotus Notes, so tell us why you think your plugin should be doing this. I.e., what you want to have happen that is not happening now?

Comment: I can see my widget with the Actions bar that contains two buttons. Also I see a list with three items ("One", "Two", "Three"). When I double click one of these items a message appears. The same when I click menu bar button. See here  http://clip2net.com/s/3h2neer. When I click an email address nothing happens because I dont know how to listen this event.

Comment: WARNING! Clicking on the link in the above comment, and then clicking on the graphic, brought up a malware page!  As to your issue, I don't know enough about the plugin architecture to help you, but I think you may want to look into using the Live Text feature that's built into Lotus Notes: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/09032009125637AMWEB7TF.htm